# python3 : Cannot Import cv2 : DLL load failed after installing opencv_contrib modules

Tags: python, opencv, python-3.x, python-3.4

I had been using cv2 in python on Windows 7 for basic image processing , but wanted xfeatured2d from the opencv_contrib package. 
I followed the instructions given in 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vp0AbhXXTrw 
up till the point of building the `ALL_BUILD` and `INSTALL` on release and debug mode and creating the system variable.

I couldn't make the sample projects since I use the express version of Visual Studio 2012 and the UI was different from what has been shown in the video , but I think that is just for testing and isn't essential to use the modules in python.

Now the problem I am facing is that my python 3.4 in which earlier I had earlier used cv2  is longer identifying cv2 package and throws the following error.

```
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
```

Answer (score 1):

I installed latest OpenCV from Git master on Ubuntu 12.10 with Python 3.2 and 3.3 bindings.

But if you want at Window check below given Link

[Open CV Package Installation](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/)

if Ubuntu before I did for Linux:

you have the *-dev package installed for your version of Python

**sudo apt-get install python3.3-dev**

Comment: I didnt know what to do from the downloaded file , so I followed the instructions mentioned in [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vp0AbhXXTrw)
I used CMake to make the solution file(.sln) for installation .  Built the ALL_BUILD and INSTALL on debug and release mode on visual studio in the .sln file created and made the system variable giving the path of the mentioned variables.
I still cant use the modules of the contib package.

Comment: I edited the above comment to tell everything that I did. Can you tell me how I should move ahead.

Comment: Oh i'did not checked the full comment that u put...   Whats error coming ,,,as of now

Comment: I removed the cv2 files from python, reinstalled it for python and then built the ALL_BUILD and INSTALL again and put in the system variable and path .
Now the import cv2 is working but there is no module as cv2.xfeatures2d.

>>> import cv2
>>> help(cv2.xfeatures2d)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    help(cv2.xfeatures2d)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'xfeatures2d'